# Averaging the column F3:F breaks as script adds new rows above row 3

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

I have Google Sheet connected via Zapier to automatically add a new row to my spreadsheet everyone time someone fills out a satisfaction survey on my website. I have **=AVERAGE(F3:F)** as the top row to show running averages of numerical values.

Problem is, when Zapier adds a new row, it seems to use the "Insert 1 Above" on Row 3, thus the formula changes automatically to `=AVERAGE(F4:F)` and the cell outputs **#DIV/0!** divide by zero error. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the range F3:F will become F4:F if a new row is inserted above the 3rd. You should change either the insertion rule or the range, so that insertion happens inside the range.

If your cell F2 does not have numeric data (chances are it's either the name of the column or is blank), then you can use `average(F2:F)` which give the same result as `average(F3:F)` but will auto-expand at insertion.

A solution not relying on the content of F2 is

```
=(sum(F2:F)-F2)/(count(F2:F)-count(F2))
```

This formula always agrees with `average(F3:F)`, and is preserved by insertion above row 3.